# Output of python script like if it's typed in interactive mode

Tags: shell-script, python, io-redirection, tee, buffer

I have a python file and I want to obtain the output just like I'm typing the content in interactive mode (like this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59008423 but with a shell script)

I try with this shell script `script.sh`

```
# script.sh
#!/bin/sh
printf "print(\"one\")\nprint(\"two\")\n" | tee /dev/fd/3 | python -i 1>/dev/fd/3 2>/dev/fd/3
```

and run

```
$ sh script.sh 3>&1
```

and get the output

```
print("one")
print("two")
Python 3.11.6 (main, Nov 14 2023, 09:36:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> one
>>> two
>>>
```

instead of what I expect

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Nov 14 2023, 09:36:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("one")
one
>>> print("two")
two
>>>
```

I think that the problem is that `python` command has a stdin buffer.

Comment: The tool for this exact task is available.  Read `man expect``.